# Why does the console close after I type yes?

Tags: c#, console, calculator

I was making a calculator in C#. Here is the multiplication part---

```
using System;
static class calculator 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    welcome:
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my calculator, please press enter to         continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide?");
    string x = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    if (x == "multiply") 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first value");
        decimal value1multiply = Convert.ToDecimal( Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second value" );
        decimal value2multiply = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Result =");
        Console.WriteLine(value1multiply * value2multiply);
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using my calculator!Do you still want to use it?Please answer in 'yes' or 'no' and press 'enter'");
        Console.ReadLine();
        string yesorno =Console.ReadLine();
        if (yesorno == "yes") 
        {
            goto welcome;
        }
         if (yesorno == "no") 
         {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
         }
       }
```

When I type 'yes' when it asks me to, the console should lead me to welcome. But instead, it does not lead me anywhere and remains blank. When I press enter again, the console closes. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

What I have tried:

I tried removing the environment.exit(0), thinking that the console was leading me to that but it did not help. I even tried typing the code in Visual Studio, but no difference in the outcome. (I use sharp develop)

Comment: instead of goto - use while with condition. goto shouldn't be used, its considered bad practice

Comment: the string is obviously not no and not yes - thats why it still closed upon you removing environment.exit. consider checking the value of yesorno with a breakpoint

Comment: remocve the console.readline before     string yesorno =Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Ok I see now, thanks for the answers guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the use of `goto`, which is often frowned upon, you are using one too much `ReadLine` call.

Here:

```
Console.ReadLine();
string yesorno = Console.ReadLine();
```

Maybe you typed `yes` and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice. In that case `yesorno` would be empty and your check would fail. The first entry is swallowed by the first `ReadLine` that didn't got assigned to a variable.

Comment: Thanks great answer fixed the problem completly.

Comment: You are welcome. Learn to get familiar with your debugger. That will help you next time. Set a breakpoint on the line you want to investigate. Then you would have seen it was hit *after* you typed *yes*.